# VB.NET - Accessing A Dataset From Within A Threaded Class Instance?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, dataset

I was using the following code within a class and creating an instance of that class from within my main form (Main.vb):

```
Dim count As Integer = Main.DbDataSet.Accounts.Count
```

This was returning the count of accounts within my database.

After changing the code so that I could run this in a background thread to save locking up the program, as more data is processed after this point, the count was returning 0 each time.

Is it possible to access my DbDataSet within a threaded process (Another class)?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I presume you have to read more on threading. This is to ensure that you are aware that you are playing with a double edged blade (Threading). There are few good material which you can find in net. Namely [threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) in C#.

Now, with the limited knowledge on what you are trying to do at your end; following code plot a blue print on how the code should look like.

```
class YourForm
{
    private DataSet dataSet;
    public int Count { get; set; }
    SynchronizationContext runningContext;
    public YourForm()
    {
    }
    void FillData()
    {
        //fill your dataset with required data
    }
    void ProcessInWorker()
    {
        runningContext=SynchronizationContext.Current;
        Two secondClass = new Two();
        secondClass.DoWork +=secondClass_DoWork;
        secondClass.RunWorkerCompleted +=secondClass_RunWorkerCompleted;
        YourRequest re=new YourRequest()
        {
            DatasetToSend=dataSet
        }
        secondClass.RunWorkerAsync(re);
    }

    void secondClass_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null) throw e.Error;
        YourResponse cResponse = e.Result as YourResponse;
        if (cResponse == null) return;

        dataSet = cResponse.RefilledData;//latest data will be here on completion of worker thread.

        //if you want you can update latest count in some UI control say txtRecordCount
        runningContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate
            {
                txtRecordCount.Text=//give your row count here;
            }), null);

    }
    void secondClass_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            YourRequest cRequest = e.Argument as YourRequest;
            cRequest.DatasetToSend = RefillData();
            YourResponse cResponse=new YourResponse()
            {
                RefilledData=cRequest.DatasetToSend
            };
            e.Result = cResponse;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw 
        }
        }
    DataSet RefillData()
    {
       //put your logic here to refill the data in dataset
        //return the dataset;
    }
}
class Two : BackgroundWorker
{
    //sub classing background worker and rest of your own 
    //logic which you are planning for second class. 
}
class YourRequest
{
    public YourRequest ()
    {
    }
    public DataSet DatasetToSend{get;set;}
}
class YourResponse
{
    public YourResponse()
    {
    }
    public DataSet RefilledData { get; set; }
}
```